# How to print & preview any document in C# - but not using crystal report?

Tags: c#, printing

How to print & preview any document in C# - but not using crystal report ?

ex.: i want to preview & print 6 variable from my C# program

thank's for any help

Answer (score 2):

[printpreviewdialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printpreviewdialog.aspx)

Here's [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/SUPrintPreviewDialog.aspx) that you can refer to.